# Pandas Loc with condition statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using loc on pandas data frame which has an index on indicator columns. In the above picture, you can see that after applying loc with the condition I am getting a boolean list. Is there any way I can get the values instead of boolean. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Sic.jpg)

Comment: Something like this? `data.loc[data['Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant']>400]`

Comment: @Umer Ijaz is your objective to filter the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.loc['Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant', data.loc['Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant']>400]
```

the first `'Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant'` means that you want this row, and the `data.loc['Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant']>400` is your boolean vector

Comment: Thanks @ theletz

Comment: Have you tested first code? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html